# What determines the From and BCC for a mass email

Tags: massemailmessage

Is there a way to set/change the From or the BCC address for a mass email? Or are these both determined by the user creates the email template being used for the mass email? If the From and BCC ARE determined by the creator of an mail template, then does the "created by" user get overridden by the "modified by" user? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

I have tried to do Google searches to find out this information prior to resorting to asking the question in this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Mass email is sent as the user in the current execution context. In other words, the user that sends or schedules to send a mass email will be the delivery address and display name by default.

In Apex Code, you can specify an alternate Reply To address and/or a display name, both of which default to the user sending the email. If you specify a BCC, one copy is sent to the sender's email address.

The creator or modifier of a template has no effect on the display name, from address, or BCC address. For more information, I suggest reading the Help section on Mass Emails.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So it appears that it would be the user that is logged in that schedules or sends the mass email. Prior to asking the question here, I attempted to read the Help sections on Mass emails, but did not find anything that provided the answer you gave. Perhaps I missed something in my investigation, or did not read the correct Help section. If you have a link for the Help page that DOES provide this information, please let me know what that would be. I would guess that others could benefit from this link as well. Thanks again for the help.